# How to remove an article from kindle and Amazon cloud permanently

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I have kindle paperwhite (firmware version 5.4.4.2). My view settings are:
On Device | My Items | Collection

**Issue :** After long press on article and selecting "Remove from device", article is still visible, though now in "grey". It is also still present on Amazon cloud.

**Expected behavior :**
Article is removed from device and cloud. It is nowhere to be seen. Nor device nor cloud.

**My workaround :**
After removing article, I move out to created "Deleted articles" collection. From time to time, I log into Amazon and manually delete articles from this collection. Last time I  had to done by groups of five as there was no option to delete them all. Very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you add the articles to your device in the first place?

In my case, articles generally land up in my Kindle Paperwhite with the help of services like Amazon's own [Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle) or third party apps like [Send to Kindle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tchami.kindle). Most of these services have a configurable option to send only to device but not to cloud.

If you use the former, just uncheck Save to Amazon Cloud Drive option at https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/setup/. You may also want to choose which device should the content be sent to.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your Kindle content via the Amazon website.

Here's a help article: [Remove Items from Your Content Library](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-5?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201252650&qid=1415310215&sr=1-5)